# Cell text not wrapping into a new line (html table)

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

First, I'll show you how it appears atm:

[image]

As you can see, the cell max width is working but the text is not getting wrapped into a new line, it is overflowing out of the cell instead.

This is the css I have set to the table:

```
border-spacing: 0 5px;
table-layout: fixed;
word-wrap:break-word;
```

This is the css I have set to that specific cell:

```
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
max-width: 100px;
```

Comment: and where is html code ?

Comment: I could add it but it isn't html per se, it's thymeleaf so it's a bit messy. Actually it's a pretty big thymeleaf html, but just think it's a regular table, it should be working anyways.

Comment: then there is problem, might be from html...this would help us to provide correct answer, cannot assume only CSS if you don't post html. If only CSS, you might see that won't work again

Comment: Already fixed it myself with: "white-space: initial" in the cell

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it adding this to the cell:

```
white-space: normal;
```